# Unable start gunicorn.sock after python 3.6 update

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a `Django` App using `Gunicorn` + `Python3` + `Nginx`. Before updating to python 3.6 everything was working. But after update I cant seem to create a gunicorn sock  file. I use below script to run the Gunicorn.

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME=yogavidya                              #Name of the application (*)
DJANGODIR=/home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim/     # Django project directory (*)
SOCKFILE=/home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim/run/gunicorn.sock        # we will communicate using this unix socket (*)
USE=ytsejam                                        # the user to run as (*)
GROUP=webdata                                     # the group to run as (*)
NUM_WORKERS=1                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn (*)
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yogavidya.settings.base           # which settings file should Django use (*)
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=yogavidya.wsgi                     # WSGI module name (*)

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source /home/ytsejam/.virtualenvs/yv_dev/bin/activate

workon yv_dev
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)

exec /home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim/gunicorn --name=$NAME --workers=$NUM_WORKERS --env=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  --pythonpath /home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim --user ytsejam --bind=unix:/home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim/run/gunicorn.sock yogavidya.wsgi:application
```

When I check the output message showing   status  service which runs script, behaviour changes time to time if it fails :

```
● yogavidya.service - Yogavidya gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/yogavidya.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-03-27 13:13:36 BST; 10min ago
  Process: 14393 ExecStart=/home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim/gunicorn_start.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 14393 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 27 13:13:36 ytsejam gunicorn_start.sh[14393]:   File "/home/ytsejam/.virtualenvs/yv_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 117, in __init__
Mar 27 13:13:36 ytsejam gunicorn_start.sh[14393]:     super(UnixSocket, self).__init__(addr, conf, log, fd=fd)
Mar 27 13:13:36 ytsejam gunicorn_start.sh[14393]:   File "/home/ytsejam/.virtualenvs/yv_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 32, in __init__
Mar 27 13:13:36 ytsejam gunicorn_start.sh[14393]:     self.sock = self.set_options(sock, bound=bound)
Mar 27 13:13:36 ytsejam gunicorn_start.sh[14393]:   File "/home/ytsejam/.virtualenvs/yv_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 46, in set_options
Mar 27 13:13:36 ytsejam gunicorn_start.sh[14393]:     if err[0] not in (errno.ENOPROTOOPT, errno.EINVAL):
Mar 27 13:13:36 ytsejam gunicorn_start.sh[14393]: TypeError: 'OSError' object is not subscriptable
Mar 27 13:13:36 ytsejam systemd[1]: yogavidya.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 27 13:13:36 ytsejam systemd[1]: yogavidya.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 27 13:13:36 ytsejam systemd[1]: yogavidya.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When I try to restart it , I get success message and output becomes

```
yogavidya.service - Yogavidya gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/yogavidya.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-03-27 13:25:55 BST; 1s ago
 Main PID: 14590 (gunicorn)
   CGroup: /system.slice/yogavidya.service
           └─14590 /home/ytsejam/.virtualenvs/yv_dev/bin/python3 /home/ytsejam/public_html/abctasarim/gunicorn --name=yogavidya --workers=1 --env=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yogavidya.settings.base --pythonpath /home

Mar 27 13:25:55 ytsejam systemd[1]: Started Yogavidya gunicorn daemon.
Mar 27 13:25:55 ytsejam gunicorn_start.sh[14590]: Starting yogavidya as ytsejam
```

But still I cant see the sock file inside `"run"` folder. How can I fix gunicorn script to start sock file ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks to me like a bug in gunicorn. You may give a try patching sock.py, changing `err[0]` with `err.errno` (see traceback above)

Comment: you saved my days . thank you fernandezcuesta